# reorder certain cell UICollectionView without moving few cells ios objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am working on app and using `LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout` for drag and drop cells in collection view. I want to make few cells non-movable, so if we will drag/drop any movable cell, non-movable cell should not be moved from it's position. for example if I mark cell at position **3 non-movable** and I drag cell from position **5** to position **2**, cell at position **3** should not move from it's position and cell at position **2** should move to position **4** not on position **3**.

Hopefully, you guys understand this.

Thanks in advance.

Yousuf S.